# Recebi um voto antes mesmo da resposta ser publicada

Tags: suporte, bug, status-nãorepro, votos

Já tinha visto isso acontecer, mas eu não tinha certeza por isso não comentei aqui.

Agora há pouco aconteceu novamente e posso afirmar que realmente acontece. Agora tenho certeza.

Estava respondendo essa pergunta, mas eu ainda não tinha publicado a resposta, estava ainda digitando e formatando.

Eu me distraí com outra coisa, então deixei tudo aberto por uns 3 minutos. Quando voltei para terminar o que estava digitando, percebi que já tinha um voto positivo. Mas eu ainda não tinha clicado no botão de "salvar" e tampouco tinha terminado de escrever.

Eu sei que o sistema salva o que escreve como um rascunho, porém, o sistema permite que mesmo o rascunho, sem ter sido "oficialmente" publicado, seja visto publicamente dando acessibilidade a votações?

Aqui o tópico: [Como somar a coluna de uma tabela em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107304/como-somar-a-coluna-de-uma-tabela-em-php/107335#107335)

Houve outros casos onde comentei sobre isso, foi num caso onde escrevi uma resposta e achei estranho alguém ter tido tempo de votar e comentar menos de 1 segundo depois que publiquei. Fiquei indagando como que a pessoa leu, interpretou, votou e comentou tão rápido pois era um texto relativamente longo.

Então eu acho que há algo errado no sistema. Pois está publicando mesmo antes de salvar. Acho que causa uma confusão muito grande porque enquanto digita algo você ainda está revisando e pode encontrar algo ambíguo, alguma falha e enquanto corrige outra pessoa pode ler essa versão ainda em edição e interpretar errado, baseado num contexto diferente da publicação final.

Comment: Mas como tinha um voto positivo se durante a edição da resposta, nem aparece nenhum indicador de voto enquanto a resposta não for publicada. Você teria um screenshot mostrando como você consegue ver votos *durante* a edição?

Comment: É isso que pergunto! Eu acho que o sistema está publicando o rascunho. Daí aparece os botões de voto e tudo mais. Não fiz screenshot. Mas tenho certeza que aconteceu. Das outras vezes que percebi, eu não tinha muita certeza então nunca perguntei aqui pois poderia ser bobeira minha. Mas agora tenho certeza de que aconteceu mesmo.

Comment: Mas como você **percebeu** os votos antes de salvar?

Comment: Tá estranho. Pode ser interpretação errada minha mas a resposta foi dada 11:25 do dia 8 e o voto foi dado às 00:00: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/107335/timeline#voteaggregate_ Será que não tem o horário do voto? O sistema está dando voto automático para a pessoa?

Comment: @bigown O sistema mascara o horário real dos votos, mostra sempre 00:00 e o total agregado de votos no dia. Então a timeline não é confiável para apurar isso. Aliás, que bom que usuários comuns agora têm acesso a essa timeline, eu pensava em abrir um feature-request pedindo isso :)

Comment: Entendi. Não sei se é importante porque tem como saber o horário de outra forma. E não sei o que isto exporia. A pergunta foi postada 11:25:37 e o voto foi recebido 11:29:17. Pelo menos é o que o site informa, não sei se ele distorce essa informação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4793/daniel-omine?tab=reputation

Comment: @bigown como se faz para ir ver o timeline?

Comment: @bfavaretto, porque apareceu notificação de voto enquanto digitava.. rsrs

Comment: @JorgeB. Na mão, use este padrão (não precisa usar a âncora, obviamente). Ou use uma extensão do navegador que coloque um *link* no *post*.

Comment: Essas páginas com histórico acho que não é suficiente para determinar a timeline das ações. Porque pode ter registrado o horário em que o rascunho foi salvo como se fosse uma postagem definitiva e não necessariamente o horário em que realmente salvei.

Comment: O @bigown parece estar certo, Daniel.

Comment: Conseguiu encontrar o problema, bfavaretto? o utlimo post do bigown fala do log no link, mas como eu comentei em seguida, o log pode estar errado também. Eu tehno certeza do que vi na minha tela. Já expliquei isso umas 2 ou 3 vezes aqui. Só postei mesmo porque dessa vez eu vi acontecer. E já tinha experimentado isso diversas vezes desde que comecei a frequentar o stack.. Isso já tem 1 ano, mas é a primeira vez que reporto. Repetindo, a data de postagem no log pode ser a data do rascunho. Pode ter um bug nisso aí.

Comment: Os dados que eu enxergo são os mesmos que o bigown citou. O Gabe já está sabendo do caso e deve encaminhar um diagnóstico com os desenvolvedores do site.

Answer (score 3):

Até onde a gente saiba, é tecnicamente impossível que isso aconteça. Posts não são salvos como posts antes de serem enviados, e votos não podem ser dados em coisas que não são posts.

Comment: Estava estudando o assunto "timeline" e vi algo curioso, o *daily summary* é um evento que fica registrado antes mesmo que a pergunta ou resposta exista: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/4738/timeline

Comment: @brasofilo Minha timeline não é necessariamente igual à sua... Pode botar uma screenshot?

Comment: é fato... é o primeiro evento, abaixo de tudo: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CqyLb.png - imagino que é só pro-forma, parece que todas as timelines começam à 00:00 do dia do post

Comment: @brasofilo Sim, é isso mesmo. O *daily summary* não é um evento "de verdade", e é calculado separadamente. Então, pra ele sempre aparecer no mesmo lugar, recebe a menor data possível

Comment: @Gabe a maior menor data possível.